# NetCore how to change implementation of interface in runtime

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

I am working with Net Core and dependency injection and have the following case:

```
var rootInstance = container.Resolve<Root>();
rootInstance.Run();

container.Use<IGrandChild, FirstGrandChild>();
var root1Instance = parentContainer.Resolve<Root>();
root1Instance.Run();

container.Use<IGrandChild, SecondGrandChild>();
var root2Instance = parentContainer.Resolve<Root>();
root2Instance.Run();

var secondGrandChild = new SecondGrandChild()
{
    Description = "Custom Description"
};

container.User<IGrandChild>(secondGrandChild);
root2Instance = parentContainer.Resolve<Root>();
root2Instance.Run();


Expected response:
# GrandChild
# FirstGrandChild
# SecondGrandChild Default
# SecondGrandChild Custom Description
```

(Classes used: https://gist.github.com/lvitti/4f531479037bd335d1c118208b3dfb6b)

I want to know if it is possible to do this with dependency injection or other method.

I tried with many packages and none offer that functionality or i couldn't find a concrete example of how to implement it.

- Autofac
- Castle Windsor
- Lamar
- Ninject
- LightInject
- SimpleInjector

Comment: change the reference and rebuild the container, a container which supports multiple implementations

Comment: I updated the question, already tried many packages and I couldn't implement it

Comment: what is this `User<IGrandChild, SecondGrandChild>`, this isn't how you register dependencies what is the user function?

Comment: you  usually register using `services.AddScoped<IGrandChild, FirstGrandChild>();`

Comment: I put it as a pseudocode, to represent a call to the container and indicate that from that moment a new class will be used to instantiate the objects of that interface.

Comment: I can really understand why you would need this in the first place.  Generally you can use decorators or factories to resolve the instance you need.  But I would say the easiest way to do this using built in .net without having to rebuild the service provider each time (because that is an expensive operation).  Would be just register bother services and then take in an IEnumerable<IGrandChild> and resolve it your self or don't use dependency injection and make it a dependency

Comment: I think the best way is to do it as you indicate. For that I should use some framework that allows to define some custom handler. Decorator or Factory wouldn't be an option because I see a lot of complication in the implementation for having a lot of levels, or i'm wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Every container has a facility for registration of multiple implementations, So Castle Windsor do this like below:
Register Implementations:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyService>()
        .ImplementedBy<MyServiceImpl>()
        .Named("myservice.default"),
    Component.For<IMyService>()
        .ImplementedBy<OtherServiceImpl>()
        .Named("myservice.alternative"),
);
```

Resolve an implementation based on a decision in runtime:

```
string impName = "myservice.alternative"; // specify it based on your decision rule
IMyService service = container.Resolve<IMyService>(impName);
```

Comment: I understand, the problem is that I need to solve the Root Object and that through the dependency manager be resolve a ChildNode and within by default be resolve the GrandChild, in a certain condition be resolve FirstGrandChild and in another SecondGrandChild